# Check todays date with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How to check todays date with sql? I wrote this:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM buy_items WHERE ordered_date = date('Y-m-d')")
```

But its not outputting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM buy_items WHERE ordered_date = CURDATE()")
```

you can get current date from following SQL functions:

```
 SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

thanks

Comment: Appreciating. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

There is Now() function in MySQL:

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM buy_items WHERE ordered_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```